# Keep the same image scale after mosaicking

Tags: google-earth-engine, scale, image-mosaic

I am trying to keep the same original image scale after creating a mosaic with the same images. But when I try to add in a map this image I can´t configure the visualized parameters.

The problem is the image is never shown, it seems to be all masked.

Is there any way to keep the image scale and can be possible to see the image after?

I used this function:

```
var composite_free_mosaic_nova = composite_free_mosaic.resample('bilinear').reproject({
  crs: projecao.projection().crs(),
  scale: 30
});
```

After the mosaicking the nominal scale was: 111319.49079327357. And I try to keep in 30 meters.

My code link is this one:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bd6aec5ffd9f98cb2d0284e5c1ece421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the reproject without resampling and that should work just fine.

```
var composite_free_mosaic_nova = composite_free_mosaic.reproject({
  crs: projecao.projection().crs(),
  scale: 30
});
```

The nominal scale stays that way for temporary layers as earth engine processes based on its pyramid system and regardless of what the scale of input layer is, it is able to output products with higher resolution. You can see more about this stuff directly from them [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections) and also [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works just fine!!